# Nginx dynamic wildcard subdomain for dynamic url of a domain

Tags: nginx, yii2, subdomain

I want to configure nginx.conf for the below url

domain.com/user/suvojit => suvojit.domain.com

Till now my nginx configuration is as below

```
server {
listen 80; ## listen for ipv4

server_name domain.com;
root        /var/www/html/project/frontend/web/;
index       index.php;

access_log  /var/www/html/project/vagrant/nginx/log/frontend-access.log;
error_log   /var/www/html/project/vagrant/nginx/log/frontend-error.log;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
    deny all;
}}
```

I am using Yii2 application. Is there anything need to specify there?

Comment: You never mentioned what you exactly want? You want `domain.com/user/suvojit` to redirect to `suvojit.domain.com` and what happens when the redirect is done? What does `suvojit.domain.com` serve?

Comment: Actually it will open domain.com/user/suvojit page when suvojit.domain.com hit in browser. I don't know it will be done using nginx configuration or not. I am using Yii application. Is there anything should configure in application route for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You need to had a server block to your nginx config

```
server {

listen 80; ## listen for ipv4

server_name ~^(?<user>[^.]+)\.example\.com$;

return 301 http://example.com/user/$user;

}
```

You also need to make sure that you make a wildcard subdomain entry in your DNS so that `*.domain.com` resolves to your server